# Envers, there is a default name column for withModifiedFlag?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I need to do a report that says which fields has been changed of a specific table. So I found this attribute on Envers to identify those fields: `withModifiedFlag=true`. I known that I can do just for the fields that I want or for the whole table.

**Do I have to set each field of my entity with the `modifiedColumnName` or there is a default name for those columns?**

I tried to create a column `field_name_modified` with type boolean and with integer, but it didn't work. Maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume the following entity example

```
@Entity
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
public class SomeEntity {
   private String customerName;
}
```

Hibernate Envers will use the name of the field / property to determine the prefix portion of the modified column name and then append the default suffix value **_MOD**.

That means for the example entity above, the modified column name is **customerName_MOD**.

You can specify your own *modifiedColumnName* value, which will still have the suffix appended, but using that attribute is typically unnecessary if you wish to use the default behavior.

```
@Entity
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
public class SomeEntity {
   @Audited(modifiedColumnName = "CUSTOMER_NAME")
   private String customerName;
}
```

The above example would use **CUSTOMER_NAME_MOD**.

The data-type used should whatever your dialect uses for **boolean** values.